# With $A$ an open real set, is $\overline{A}^\complement\cap A^\complement $ necessarily open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

With $A$ an open real set, is $\overline{A}^\complement\cap A^\complement $ necessarily open?

My intuition says that it is not, but I'm having trouble coming up with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\bar{A} \supseteq A$, so $\bar{A}^{c} \subseteq A^c$ and $\bar{A}^{c} \cap A^c = \bar{A}^{c}$.

Since $\bar{A}$ is closed,...

Comment: Ah, thank you. My intuition was wrong.